# Python w+ only matching one character of word

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex

```
<TAG>foo</TAG>[\s"\w]*\(born[\s<>\w/,]*(\w+)
```

And this text

```
word word</TAG> "word" <TAG>foo</TAG> (born <TAG>words</TAG>, August 19, 1900
```

However, said regex only matches the last character of the 0 in 1900. In other words there is  a match from "word" all the way to 1900, but only the last 0 is captured.

Why is that happening?

Comment: `[\s<>\w/,]*` eats up everything up until the last `\w`.

Comment: can I force it to take the last 4 chars of the match?

Answer (score 1):

With `[\s<>\w/,]*(\w+)`, the `[\s<>\w/,]*` will eat up everything and leave just enough character for `(\w+)` to match (which is the last character). This explains what you get.

If you want to get `1900`, then you can make a small modification:

```
<TAG>foo</TAG>[\s"\w]*\(born[\s<>\w/,]*\b(\w+)
                                       ^^
```

`\b` will match a word boundary, and forces `(\w+)` to match the last *word*<sup>1</sup> - since there is no word boundary inside a *word*.

<sub><sup>1</sup> "Word" is a sequence of one or more characters that is defined by `\w`. Depending on the mode, `\w` may include only ASCII characters, or it may include Unicode characters.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`[\s<>\w/,]*` is eating everything from your text. If its always fixed four digit, then you can use `\d\d\d\d` or `\d{4}` or if you are stick to \w then its `\w{4}` or `\w\w\w\w`.

I am talking about replacing the `(\w+)` from the end. Which means minimum one or more.